# Core Audio error when running on 64-bit processor

Tags: ios, c, audio, core-audio

Working with some Core Audio code written before 64-bit processors were introduced in iOS. The app compiles and runs fine on 32 bit processors, but when I try an run on an iPhone 5s, I get two compiler errors.

```
AQRecorderState ars;    

static void AQInputCallback(void                                 *aqRecorderState,  // AQRecorderState struct
                            AudioQueueRef                        inQ,
                            AudioQueueBufferRef                  inBuffer,
                            const AudioTimeStamp                 *timestamp,
                            unsigned long                        inNumPackets,
                            const AudioStreamPacketDescription   *mDataFormat){

    AQRecorderState *pArs = (AQRecorderState *)aqRecorderState;

    if (inNumPackets == 0 && pArs->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket != 0)
        inNumPackets = inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize / pArs->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket;    


    // This line returns an error "No matching function call for 'AudioFileWritePackets'" 
    if (AudioFileWritePackets(pArs->mAudioFile,
                              false, 
                              inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                              mDataFormat, 
                              pArs->mCurrentPacket, 
                              &inNumPackets, 
                              inBuffer->mAudioData) == noErr){

        pArs->mCurrentPacket += inNumPackets;  // advance packet index pointer
    }

    // don't re-queue the sound buffers if stop has been pressed
    if (!pArs->mIsRunning)
        return;

    // send the buffer back to the queue for more data
    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(pArs->mQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Getting the same error when trying to create a new Audio Queue. I believe it's because of the AQInputCallback line...

```
// Error: No matching function for call to 'AudioQueueNewInput'
AudioQueueNewInput(&ars.mDataFormat, 
                   AQInputCallback, 
                   &ars, 
                   NULL, 
                   kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 
                   0, 
                   &ars.mQueue);
```

Thanks for your help! I've read through the Learning Core Audio book multiple times and searched SO and the internet for days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is likely due to inNumPackets, which is defined as `unsigned long`. In a 32-bit process `long` is 32 bits whereas in a 64 bit process `long` is 64 bits. The parameter in `AudioFileWritePackets` expects a `UInt32*`. You can the long to and from a temp variable to make the call:

```
UInt32 inNumPacketsTmp = inNumPackets;
if (AudioFileWritePackets(pArs->mAudioFile,
                          false, 
                          inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                          mDataFormat, 
                          pArs->mCurrentPacket, 
                          &inNumPacketsTemp, 
                          inBuffer->mAudioData) == noErr){
    inNumPackets = inNumPacketsTmp;
    pArs->mCurrentPacket += inNumPackets;  // advance packet index pointer
}
```

I'm not sure about the second one.

Comment: Yes, @jacket that definitely seems to be the error. What's the best way to pass a UInt32 pointer on a 64 bit processor? I've tried all kinds of ways from NSUInteger, NSNumber, uint32_t, etc.

Comment: @user3307895 - I've updated my answer with an example.